# Recurrent Python Neural Networks - Reshape () Error

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, reshape

The script below creates the arrays for data prediction using recurring neural networks, If I set the period to 4, the script runs, but I have a 5 value input, how to fix my reshape?

**DATA SET**

```
3519    2019-10-31 19:00:00 55.6716
3550    2019-10-31 20:00:00 70.6110
3664    2019-10-31 21:00:00 97.0794
3789    2019-10-31 22:00:00 65.6901
3911    2019-10-31 23:00:00 65.3645
```

**SCRIPT**

```
base = base.dropna()
base = base.iloc[:,2].values

periodos = 5
previsao_futura = 1 # horizonte

X = base[0:(len(base) - (len(base) % periodos))]
X_batches = X.reshape(-1, periodos, 1)

y = base[1:(len(base) - (len(base) % periodos)) + previsao_futura]
y_batches = y.reshape(-1, periodos, 1)

X_teste = base[-(periodos + previsao_futura):]
X_teste = X_teste[:periodos]
X_teste = X_teste.reshape(-1, periodos, 1)
y_teste = base[-(periodos):]
y_teste = y_teste.reshape(-1, periodos, 1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ConsumptionAnalysisNeuralNetwork.py", line 40, in <module>
    y_batches = y.reshape(-1, periodos, 1)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (5,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If base is of size 5 (e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4]`):

```
>>> base[1:6]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Which is size 4 not 5. So you need to make sure that `len(base) >= periodos + 1`.

or replace
`y = base[1:(len(base) - (len(base) % periodos)) + previsao_futura]`
with `y = base[0:(len(base) - (len(base) % periodos))]`.

It kind of depends on the purpose of `previsao_futura`.